# can anyone explain how this works mapping(string =&gt; Asset) private assetStore;?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, mapping

I have used mappings in solidity 
for example this line is from solidity documentation

```
mapping(address => uint) shares;
```

here we are mapping addresses to uints and shares being the identifier of that mapping.
But I came across this example

```
mapping(string =&gt; Asset) private assetStore;
```

on online [tutorial](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/01/implementing-smart-contracts/) and that does not make any sense. Can you explain how this works or is there any syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

`&gt;` stands for > (gt = 'greater than', lt = 'less than' for the opposite effect)

I'd imagine this is a html copy/paste syntax error - replace `&gt;` with `>` and you should be good to go!